# Curl error: Failed to connect to ipaddress port 8080

Tags: php, curl, cpanel

problem

```
  Curl error: Failed to connect to 103.16.101.52 port 8080: Connection refusedresource(4) of type (mysql result)
```

- code snippets works in localsystem.
- it's not working prod enviornment.

php curl snippet

```
try {

    $runfile = 'http://103.16.101.52:8080/sendsms/bulksms?username=XXX&password=XXX&type=0&dlr=1&destination='. $row['phone_number'] . '&source=XXX&message='.$message;

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $runfile);

    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $content = curl_exec ($ch);



    if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
    {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
    }
    var_dump($result);die;
    curl_close ($ch); 

    } 
    catch (\Exception $e) {

    $message = $e->getMessage();
    print_r($message);
    die;
    }
```

- i googled and found

  ```
     CURLE_NOT_BUILT_IN (4)

     A requested feature, protocol or option was not found built-in in 
    this libcurl due to a build-time decision. This means that a feature 
     or option was not enabled or explicitly disabled when libcurl was 
     built and in order to get it to function you have to get a rebuilt libcurl.
  ```
- does this error belongs ipv4 or ipv6.
- im using cpanel  please suggest.

Solution that worked for me

i tried with 80 port

```
  $runfile = 'http://103.16.101.52:80
```

Comment: `Connection refused` The server you're trying to connect to is refusing the connection. Simple as. Not a PHP, or CURL issue.

Comment: Your production system is unable to connect to that IP on that port. Maybe it's a firewall thing. Maybe that service is down or has temporarily blocked you because you made too many bad requests. It's also generally a bad idea to hard-code IP addresses. Use domain names whenever possible, as routine infrastructure changes can kill your program otherwise.

Comment: Have you tried port 80, 8080 is usually used when you have something else running that also uses 80. (I use containers and 8080 is directed to my phpmyadmin container, 80 to my Apache container)

Comment: Also, that's not an error 4 from curl, it is probably error 7 `CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to put this as a proper answer...
Use port 80, 8080 is usually used when you have something else running that also uses 80. (I use containers and 8080 is directed to my phpmyadmin container, 80 to my Apache container)

Answer (score 0):

Do a telnet 103.16.101.52 8080. If you get connected them it could be a curl/php issue. If you get a connection refused message then the server is not listening on that port on the specified ip address. The way it looks from your message, you can't connect on that port because nothing listens on that port on your server (at least at the moment you have asked the question here).